# Chrome Extension icon doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

I'm trying to make my first Chrome Extension.
It's supposed to read and modify text on specific webpages. It works fine, except the icon never shows up.

It just shows the default puzzle peice icon on both the chrome developers page and in the Chrome toolbar.

I'm using the following in my manifest.json file.

`"page_action": {
        "default_icon": "favicon2.jpg",
        "default_title": "Portal.io Deposit Calculator"
    }`

favicon2.jpg exists in the same directory as manifest.json. I've tried resizing the image, using .ico and .jpg. The image isn't perfectly square (32x33) but I thought it would resize itself anyway, right?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "icons" key at the top level:

```
"icons": {
    "16": "image16.png", //for 16x16 pixels
    "48": "image48.png", //for 48x48 pixels
    "128": "image128.png" // for 128x128 pixels
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "image16.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
```

Icons documentation here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/icons

Comment: I added the "icons" key and relevant 16, 48 and 128 versions of the icon. The icon is still not showing up anywhere.

Comment: Never mind, looks like jpg is not showing (even the documentation says that its a valid format). Try using png format

Comment: I converted them all over to .png and it seems to be working now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this in your manifest file:

```
"icons": {
    "16": "image16.png", //for 16x16 pixels
    "48": "image48.png", //for 48x48 pixels
    "128": "image128.png" // for 128x128 pixels
},
```

Make sure all the icons are in `.png` format.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add icons in both locations --- in the "icons" key and in the "default_icon" key embedded in the "action" value, as shown below.

```
"icons": {
    "16": "/images/icon-16x16.png",
    "32": "/images/icon-32x32.png",
    "48": "/images/icon-48x48.png",
    "128": "/images/icon-128x128.png"
},
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
},
"action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
        "16": "/images/icon-16x16.png",
        "32": "/images/icon-32x32.png",
        "48": "/images/icon-48x48.png",
        "128": "/images/icon-128x128.png"
    }
}
```